# Flutter - How to get mac address without using package

Tags: macos, flutter, dart, mac-address

I Know how to get mac address by using get_mac flutter package

can anyone here tell me How to Get MAC Address without using any package in flutter

Comment: Go to the package repo link and check the implementation.

Comment: I tried it by getting the code that's in get_mac package but it don't work it gives a warning saying:  

Error: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getMacAddress on channel get_mac)

Answer (score 1):

You can't really get the mac address for privacy concerns. Old versions of android may give it up, but new ones will just give you placeholders.

Answer (score 0):

Use this method

```
class GetMacAddress {
  static const MethodChannel _channel = const MethodChannel('get_mac');

  static Future<String> get macAddress async {
    final String macID = await _channel.invokeMethod('getMacAddress');
    return macID;
  }
}
```

Call it like this

```
print(GetMacAddress.macAddress);
```

Comment: This don't work, We get error saying:

MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getMacAddress on channel get_mac)

Comment: Please restart your app before calling the method.

Comment: it's not working even after full restart.